# Rust compiler/cargo cannot find crate which is installed

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am a Rust beginner and am having difficulty getting dependencies to work using Cargo. I'm following the docs on how to import crates.

In Cargo.toml I have added:

```
[dependencies]
ferris-says = "0.2"
```

Then I ran cargo build.

I have main.rs in src/main.rs. In it I attempt to import the ferris-says crate:

```
use ferris_says::say;
```

However when I run rustc main.rs, the compiler cannot find the crate ferris-says. Error:

```
1 | use ferris_says::say; // from the previous step
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `ferris_says`?
```

I have followed the docs exactly (https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started) and tried many times.

I have tried on different OS (Mac, Ubuntu) My Rust is 1.64.0.

Comment: Do you have `edition = "2021"` in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: At one point you say you ran `cargo build` and at another you say you ran `rustc main.rs`, so which did you run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I run rustc main.rs

`rustc` is a rust compiler, you don't need to use it directly. Use `cargo`, a build system that will manage your dependencies and invoke `rustc` with proper flags. So try `cargo build`.

Comment: That does it! ```cargo build``` then ```cargo run``` runs the code. Thanks for the tip :)